# Domain Stays a Cube for First 2 or 3 Frames when Baking

Tags: baking

I am attempting to complete a tutorial of a fluid simulation (MK Graphics Fluid Simulation), and everything goes great until I bake the mesh for the fluid. Once baked, the first 2 or 3 frames is a solid cube, but it then disappears, and the rest of the bake runs as normal.
I've changed the size of the domain cube and tried to offset when the various animation features trigger all to no avail. Offsetting the events just makes the cube stay solid longer.
I've tried recalculating the normals on the fluid mesh with no joy either.

Comment: Try to change domain resolution +/-1 to be sure cache is refreshed or check if fluid sim cache start is set to 1 ... Or share a simplified file, just with elements needed to reproduce the issue ... Use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I tried the above suggestions with no joy. I even switched to a different HDD for the project and started from scratch with the same result. It always happens after I bake the mesh. 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9P1GBERV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9P1GBERV/)

Comment: Upon further reflection, it happens after I add keyframes and then bake the data and then the mesh. Before keyframes, it's normal without the beginning flash frames.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9P1GBERV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9P1GBERV/)

Comment: Sorry for delay ... See answer if still actual for you. if you want to notify me you will have a more chance to catch me if you type @vklidu in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hm ... right ... Any time there is not a fluid mesh generated (start, end or even in a middle of sim) domain appears in render.

[image]

I agree it is really unwanted effect.
If we know what is causing this issue you can try to avoid it by placing a small Flow object somewhere in a domain inside an Effector and hide these helpers from Rendering (Outliner > Camera icon).

[image]

Just to be sure there would be still generated some drop of liquid (mesh).

[image]

Alternatively as another workarounds ...

- for the beginning of sim you can animate gravity value instead of scale
- you can animate Domain object's Render visibility in outliner (Camera icon)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these a try. @vklidu